# Debian second eth in VM only comes up manually

Tags: debian, kvm

I have a working eth1 second NIC in a KVM VM on Debian Jessie, but it only comes up if I add it manually after boot. My /etc/network/interfaces looks like

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.167
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

# The secondary network interface
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth0 inet static
    address 1.2.3.4
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 1.2.3.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    post-up route del default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
    post-up route add default gw 1.2.3.1 eth1
```

but after boot I only show eth0 being up with 192.168.1.1. When I add the eth1 manually like:

```
ifconfig eth1 1.2.3.4 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route del default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
route add default gw 1.2.3.1 eth1
```

it routes all traffic across public static 1.2.3.4 like it should. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

You've written `iface eth0 inet static` in the second section, but it should be `eth1`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that, now eth1 is the right IP but it still doesn't add the default gw as 1.2.3.1 for eth1, still shows default gw as 192.168.1.1 on eth0